# How do I hide a select until ng-repeat is finished?

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-repeat for the options in a select button. Every time loads, it takes a while for it to populate the select's options, so when I click the select fast enough, there's nothing in the list.

I tried adding an ng-cloak to the select element, but no dice. Any suggestions?

Comment: why not use ng-options? http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select

Comment: ng-show="options.length > 0"? It should not take too long to populate the options. You should use ng-options as already suggested.

Comment: @JonathanRowny I just happen to stumble onto that directive right now; I didn't know there was such a directive at first and was searching for the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ngDisabled](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angDisabled).

```
<select ng-disabled="dataList.length == 0" ng-optoins="item.Name for item in dataList"></select>
```